# Extract Method Object in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, automated-refactoring

Is PhpStorm able to convert a method into a class, similar to [IntelliJ's extract method object refactoring function](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/extract-method-object.html)?

If not, is manually doing this refactoring step all we can do with PhpStorm, or is there a faster way?

Comment: PhpStorm does not have this feature.

Comment: @funivan This basically answers my question, thanks.